# Command Prompt Within a WinApplication

Tags: windows, winforms, c#-4.0

Long story short, I want sort of a disabled textbox to act as a command Prompt for an application and a enabled textbox to act as the command input, like in this java application, but in C#.

[Java Application(Crafty)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17925907/Minecraft/Crafty/crafty_v0.4.png)

Answer (score 0):

This code sample does what you need: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ProcessStartDemo.aspx

Comment: Seems like what I need, I'll get back to see if it works for me.

Comment: Close, but it's a bit buggy for what I want. I might be able to tweak it a bit...